# building inbox query with threads and messages

Tags: mysql

So I have two tables for dealing with messages `threads` and `messages`.

```
messages:
id | thread | user_from | user_to | text | created

threads:
id | user_from | user_to | created | status
```

I want to build a query that would fetch me threads with:

1. the latest message for that thread
2. the id for that thread

Until now, I have been dealing with this problem by first fetching the all threads (with proper limits of course) and then getting the latest message for each thread individually.

Any thoughts?

**Update:**

Table Relation: `messages`.`thread` = `threads`.`id`

Comment: how is the two tables related?

Comment: ok i just posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
SELECT t.id, m.* FROM threads t
INNER JOIN messages m ON m.thread = t.id
WHERE m.id = 
   (SELECT id FROM messages WHERE thread = t.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

[edit] Tested and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I'm assuming that the latest ID is the latest message - if not, change the subquery to use the `created` field instead.

Comment: are you sure that `t.id` is accessible on the subquery?

Comment: Sure - or you'd never be able to restrict a subquery from the main one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.id, max(m.id) as last_message_id
from threads t
left outer join messages m on m.thread = t.id
group by t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
SELECT  a.id     AS ThreadID, 
        c.`text` AS LatestMessage
FROM    threads a 
            INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  thread, max(created) maxCreated
                FROM    messages
                GROUP BY thread
            ) b on a.id = b.thread 
            INNER JOIN messages c
                    on a.id = c.thread AND
                       b.maxCreated = c.created
```